# Nested and escaped JSON payload to flattened dictionary - python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flatten

I'm looking for any suggestions to resolve an issue I'm facing. It might seem as a simple problem, but after a few days trying to find an answer - I think it is not anymore.
I'm receiving data (StringType) in a following JSON-like format, and there is a requirement to turn it into flat key-value pair dictionary. Here is a payload sample:

```
s = """{"status": "active", "name": "{\"first\": \"John\", \"last\": \"Smith\"}", "street_address": "100 \"Y\" Street"}"""
```

and the desired output should look like this:

```
{'status': 'active', 'name_first': 'John', 'name_last': 'Smith', 'street_address': '100 "Y" Street'}
```

The issue is I can't find a way to turn original string (s) into a dictionary. If I can achieve that the flattening part is working perfectly fine.

```
import json
import collections
import ast


#############################################################
# Flatten complex structure into a flat dictionary
#############################################################
def flatten_dictionary(dictionary, parent_key=False, separator='_', value_to_str=True):
    """
    Turn a nested complex json into a flattened dictionary
    :param dictionary: The dictionary to flatten
    :param parent_key: The string to prepend to dictionary's keys
    :param separator: The string used to separate flattened keys
    :param value_to_str: Force all returned values to string type
    :return: A flattened dictionary
    """

    items = []

    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        new_key = str(parent_key) + separator + key if parent_key else key

        try:
            value = json.loads(value)
        except BaseException:
            value = value

        if isinstance(value, collections.MutableMapping):
            if not value.items():
                items.append((new_key,None))
            else:
                items.extend(flatten_dictionary(value, new_key, separator).items())
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            if len(value):
                for k, v in enumerate(value):
                    items.extend(flatten_dictionary({str(k): (str(v) if value_to_str else v)}, new_key).items())
            else:
                items.append((new_key,None))
        else:
            items.append((new_key, (str(value) if value_to_str else value)))

    return dict(items)


# Data sample; sting and dictionary
s = """{"status": "active", "name": "{\"first\": \"John\", \"last\": \"Smith\"}", "street_address": "100 \"Y\" Street"}"""
d =    {"status": "active", "name": "{\"first\": \"John\", \"last\": \"Smith\"}", "street_address": "100 \"Y\" Street"}

# Works for dictionary type
print(flatten_dictionary(d))

# Doesn't work for string type, for any of the below methods
e = eval(s)
# a = ast.literal_eval(s)
# j = json.loads(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import json
import re


def jsonify(s):
  s = s.replace('"{','{').replace('}"','}')
  s = re.sub(r'street_address":\s+"(.+)"(.+)"(.+)"', r'street_address": "\1\2\3"',s)
  return json.loads(s)
```

If you must keep the quotes around Y, try:

```
def jsonify(s):
  s = s.replace('"{','{').replace('}"','}')
  search = re.search(r'street_address":\s+"(.+)"(.+)"(.+)"',s)
  if search:
    s = re.sub(r'street_address":\s+"(.+)"(.+)"(.+)"', r'street_address": "\1\2\3"',s)
    dict_version = json.loads(s)
    dict_version['street_address'] = dict_version['street_address'].replace(search.group(2),'"'+search.group(2)+'"')
  return dict_version
```

A more generalized attempt:

```
def jsonify(s):
  pattern = r'(?<=[,}])\s*"(.[^\{\}:,]+?)":\s+"([^\{\}:,]+?)"([^\{\}:,]+?)"([^\{\}:,]+?)"([,\}])'
  s = s.replace('"{','{').replace('}"','}')
  search = re.search(pattern,s)
  matches = []
  if search:
    matches = re.findall(pattern,s)
    s = re.sub(pattern, r'"\1": "\2\3\4"\5',s)
  dict_version = json.loads(s)
  for match in matches:
    dict_version[match[0]] = dict_version[match[0]].replace(match[2],'"'+match[2]+'"')
  return dict_version
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but it doesn't work, failing with:
     RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
Also, 'street_address' is just an example, and size of JSON payload in real world very large. I was looking for more generic solution.

Comment: I wrongly put json.loads(jsonify(s)) on the first edit. Try again with return json.loads(s) only, please

Comment: Edited again to include a version that keeps the quotes around Y

Comment: Great! It works with predefined key, in this example "street_address", but it can be anything.

Comment: I'm afraid a more generalized approach won't be possible, since the json schema might be broken by different insertions of quotes on the string. You can include other keys to do the regex replacement, not only "street_address"

Comment: Added a more generalized regex pattern to match the quotes inserted on the content